# Loop not working in package

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables :- Person and bank details

```
Person table :---
person_id     employee_number
393829          X1029
648494          x9494
393939          X2299

Bank details :---

person_id       bank_form
393829         Reimb
393829         Sal
648494         Sal
393939         Common
```

Now if a particular person  has bank form as "sal" and "reimb" then "This is it" has to be printed .If he has only"common" as bank form then also nothing has to be done.
i have made a cursor for this . But line "This is it"    is not working.

```
Create or replace package body xx_bank_details
as 
procedure xx_bank_details_proc( 
ERRBUF out varchar2,
 RETCODE  out varchar2
)

Cursor c1
is 
select person_id
from person;

Cursor c2(p_person_id)
is select bank_form
from bank_details
where bank_details.person_id=p_person_id;

begin

for cur_c1 in c1
loop
        for cur_c2 in c2(c1.person_id)
        loop
        if(cur_c2.bank_details='Sal')
then
l_sal :='Sal';
end if;
if(cur_c2.bank_details='Reimb')
then
l_reimb :='Reimb';
end if;
if(cur_c2.bank_details='Common')
then
l_common :='Common';
end if;
end loop;
if (l_sal is not null and l_reimb is not null)
then
fnd_output.put_line("This is it !");
end if;

end loop;
end xx_bank_details_proc;
end xx_bank_details;
```

Comment: What a mess... What is p_person_id? If you expect to get help then build sample table and data.

Comment: p_person_id is being used below.kindly check

Comment: Your p_person_id should be declare in procedure xx_bank_details_proc. Otherwise you should get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to use SQL to isolate the records that you want to take action on.

One form would be:

```
begin
for x in (
  select person_id
  from   person
  where  exists (
           select null -- see comment below *
           from   bank_details
           where  bank_details.person_id=person.person_id and
                  bank_form in ('Sal','Reimb')
           having count(*) = 2)
loop
  fnd_output("This is it!)
end loop
end
```

There are quite a few variations on the SQL that would work, but the key issue is to push the logic into SQL rather than a cursor, especially an explicit one.

comment * : in an "exists" subquery the value projected from the subquery does not matter. The "exists" is looking to see if any row is projected regardless of how many columns or rows are included and what the values are. Selecting any of null, 1, "x", or any other literal would be equivalent, but selecting null is a nice way of saying "it doesn't matter what the value is".

Comment: i did not get the logic. pls explain hat will select null do.

Comment: i want that if a person(person_id=393829 ) has bank_form as 'Sal' and 'Reimb' then "This is It" should be printed

Comment: That sounds different to "But if the bank form is only "Sal" without "Reimb" then the table you have to print it out." to me, but what you're looking for is that a person is printed out if they have forms for BOTH "Sal" and "Reimb" and no others? Or if the have forms for BOTH "Sal" and "Reimb" and ANY others?

Comment: If the bank_details for a person is both "Reimb" and "Sal" Then "This is It" has to be printed. is the looping wrong ?

Comment: Now the query will return the person id if both a Sal and a Reimb record exists in the bank_details table, regardless of whether there are any other records.

Comment: so You are saying there is no need of cursor ?

Cant this be done the way i did it ?

Comment: If you don't need a cursor, don't use one. SQL is faster and more compact.

Comment: and where will it get printed ? isnt cursor the best way to do it

Comment: Also... the count will be 2 only if the bank_details are both sal and reimb ?

Comment: Well that's the least interesting part. OK, I put it in an anonymous PL/SQL block as an implicit cursor with a call to the fnd_output function.

Comment: The count will be 2 if it finds two rows that meet the criteria.

Comment: Thank you.. new to PL/SQL and oracle. This will surely help.

Comment: ok.... 2 rows ... 1 with bank_detail= 'Sal' and 1 with 'Reimb' right ? Cause i want the person which has both of them like the person 393829  in the above example

Answer (score 1):

your code is riddled with errors so its tough to know if you've hurriedly put this whole thing together for the stackoverflow posting or what. your main problem is that you are not resetting the three local variables to NULL on each iteration of the `C1` loop.

also your logic as stated "but if the bank form is only "Sal" without "Reimb" then the table you have to print it out" doesn't match the code in that the code is printing out if both are present.

this whole thing could be done in a single SQL statment though without the need for all those cursor loops.

Comment: But my First loop is not working .. that is i have a person with both sal and reimb.. 'This is it' should be printed.. whch is not happening. and as for the code... i just need the logic..... i have written the whole code again as i cant write the exact code here

Comment: Stop using PL/SQL loops and just find the data you want with SQL

Comment: @user2065695 - you do not need to write the code. You need to build sample tables, populate them with sample data and clearly describe the logic. As Dazzal wrote you do not need all those loops...

Comment: There are almost 100 values feeded in these tables.. so i thought Cursor will be a better option. But yes i am new to oracle. Will try to improve my coding skills